# Add colors to regions in Android Maps

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I have a requirement to add colors for regions in Android Maps as shown in picture
[image]

I already implemented it in html using Google Maps V3 & loaded html file in webview. But I have issue in adding markers.

Is it possible to implement same in native Android Google Maps??

Comment: I dont think so.....

Answer (score 2):

In Android using google Maps v2, I implemented this for 2-3 regions by adding some locations to the polygon. But Not possible to give to all the locations in an efficient way.